# Is there a function for extracting time of txt file using Python

Tags: python

How to extract time from txt file which contains 700 lines and each line has a  specific time? using Python for example in my txt file:

```
14.999682   7.119120    13.02.2018 07:06:51
19.999625   7.119110    13.02.2018 07:06:56
```

Comment: Every line has same format?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you able to read the text file? If it's delimited, grab the 4th item from each row. If it's not delimited, is it fixed width? If so, grab the value at the appropriate position in each row? If it's neither fixed width nor delimited, use a regex.

Comment: you can take a look at the `datetime.strptime` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily by reading in the file using `readlines` and then using the split method:

```
time_list = []
with open(your_filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        time_list.append(line.split()[3])
```

This will get your times in a list (`time_list`) which you can use to do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Maybe worth adding `strptime` as well as saving the results into a list?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make use of all the elements in your source file, I would recommend to read it into a pandas DataFrame.

```py
import pandas as pd

# read all data from the text file
# Since I do not know the separator whitespaces within the file I
# used a regex for any occurring white space
df = pd.read_csv('sourcefile.txt', sep=r'[\s]+', header=None)

# assign names to the columns
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'Date', 'Time']

# your list
time_list = df['Time'].to_list()
```